# EmberJS - Adding an item to the store does not update view

Tags: ember.js, model, controller, ember-data

I have a one to many relationship in the model of the application to relevantUsers. Now I want to iterate via the `{{#each}}` helper over those values. Which works.

```
content: function()
{
    return this.get('controllers.application.model.relevantUsers');
}.property('controllers.application.model.relevantUsers'),
```

And when removing an item from the relevantUsers the view updates. But when adding a new relevantUser nothing happens. The user gets added to the data store, but the view does not update. Am I missing something?

This is how I create a new user

```
// Create new user
var relevantUser = this.store.createRecord('relevantUser', relevantUserData);

// And push it to remote
relevantUser.save();
```

Comment: once it is created, push it to the relationship, something like this: "controllers.application.get('model.relevantUsers').pushObject(relevantUser)" something like that, I don't know where you have the code to add a new relevantUser, but what matters here is that you need to access the model that is assigned to 'application' and push that object to its 'relevantUsers' relationship

Comment: Thank you, you saved my life. Don't know why I can't mark this as correct. I've tingled with this for days.

Comment: you're welcome, glad to see that you can continue coding, see you!

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I've done it like [CoffeeScript] :

```
video = self.store.createRecord 'video', id: @Id, title: @Title, thumbnailUrl: @ThumbnailUrl

@Formats.map (i) -> //Formats is simple JavaScript array.
    format = self.store.createRecord 'format', itag: i.itag, quality: i.quality, resolution: i.resolution, type: i.type, url: i.url
    video.get('formats').then (f) ->
        f.pushObject format
```

The difference, is, that I use [.pushObject()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObject) method here. As @fanta wrote in his comment, you have to get array that has relationship with model, so it will notify all observers.

[More example code](https://github.com/Kuzirashi/cross-video-downloader/blob/master/lib/App.coffee#L74).